# centos 7 decrypt and encrypt library

Tags: centos, encryption, telnet

I have installed telnet server in my centos 7.

I need to make some modifications to the telnet connection to the server. I have a library to check telnet login. It is encrypted. I need a decoding method. file path is `/bin/login`

[this is file](https://filebin.net/c7ejbh2bjvek1l1z)

I tried to decrypt the file by [mcrypt](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mcrypt) tool but it asked me for a password and I don't know it

How can I encrypt and decrypt such files?

Comment: How can I encrypt and decrypt such files? @jsotola

Comment: it is unclear what you are trying to decrypt ... how does it relate to telnet?

Answer (score 1):

The file you point (`/bin/login`) is executable file, not encrypted. To make changes you need to install `util-linux....srpm` package, make changes, recompile and install it.

Check [here](https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2015/04/20/working-with-source-rpms/) how to install source package for particular package

```
yum install yum-utils rpm-build
yumdownloader --source <package>
rpm -ivh <package>
yum-builddep redis
rpmbuild -bp <package spec>
```

Comment: can u help plz how i can install it No package srpm available.

Comment: i use centos 7 system

Comment: It turns out that the /bin/login . file
Not among the files
telnet-server lib
. It's from linux centos 7 system files

Comment: @mohammedmoha, the `login` utility is part of `util-linux` package

Comment: i extract the file util-linux-2.23.2-65.el7_9.1.src.rpm using command rpm2cpio ./util-linux-2.23.2-65.el7_9.1.src.rpm | cpio -idmv . now how i can compress all files extracted
 to src.rpm file  or rpm file

Comment: @mohammedmoha, you should install, compile and install resulting `rpm`